# Error when using `on conflict` on postgresql query

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I've the following table on PostgreSQL:

```
-- Table: product_ohlcv_history

-- DROP TABLE product_ohlcv_history;

CREATE TABLE product_ohlcv_history
(
  broker_uuid uuid NOT NULL,
  product_id character varying(10) NOT NULL, -- ID of the product.
  "timestamp" character varying(50) NOT NULL, -- Timestamp when value was calculated.
  open double precision NOT NULL, -- Open price
  high double precision NOT NULL, -- High price
  low double precision NOT NULL, -- Low price
  close double precision NOT NULL, -- Close price
  volume double precision NOT NULL, -- Volume.
  timeframe integer NOT NULL, -- Timeframe of the OHLCV in seconds.
  CONSTRAINT "PK_product_ohlcv_history" PRIMARY KEY (product_id, "timestamp", broker_uuid)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE product_ohlcv_history
  OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON COLUMN product_ohlcv_history.product_id IS 'ID of the product.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN product_ohlcv_history."timestamp" IS 'Timestamp when value was calculated.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN product_ohlcv_history.open IS 'Open price';
COMMENT ON COLUMN product_ohlcv_history.high IS 'High price';
COMMENT ON COLUMN product_ohlcv_history.low IS 'Low price';
COMMENT ON COLUMN product_ohlcv_history.close IS 'Close price';
COMMENT ON COLUMN product_ohlcv_history.volume IS 'Volume.';
COMMENT ON COLUMN product_ohlcv_history.timeframe IS 'Timeframe of the OHLCV in seconds.';
```

The following query fails, giving the error

```
ERROR:  syntax error near 'on'
LINE 4: ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT PK_product_ohlcv_history do nothin...
```

This is the query:

```
insert into product_ohlcv_history (broker_uuid, product_id, timestamp, open, high, low, close, volume, timeframe) values 
('85dcfe70b81c44589a805dca647dad0c', '1INCH-BTC', '05/04/2022 04:40:00 +00:00', 0.000041, 0.0000411, 0.000041, 0.0000411, 2.67, 60), 
('85dcfe70b81c44589a805dca647dad0c', '1INCH-BTC', '05/04/2022 03:01:00 +00:00', 0.0000411, 0.0000411, 0.0000411, 0.0000411, 53.54, 60)
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT PK_product_ohlcv_history do nothing;
```

If I remove the last row, the normal insertion works. So what I'm doing wrong? I want to avoid errors if for some reason the row that I want to insert already exists.

I'm using PostgreSQL version 9.4.

Comment: `ON CONFLICT` was  introduced in 9.5 - your [unsupported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) and no longer maintained version simply doesn't support it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ON CONFLICT` was introduced in PostgreSQL 9.5. But if you are running an old and unsupported version of PostgreSQL, that's the least of your problems.